# side-operations and aggregations inside LINQ, before select

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

**Within** the following query i would like to add:

- `Trace.WriteLine(i.Name)`
- and get a count of tasks without an additional enumeration afterwards (without a separate `int count = tasks.Count()`)

#### Sample Query

```
        var tasks = (
            from i in items
            where i.IsValid
            orderby i.Priority 
            select i.GetTask())
            .Take(100);

         await TaskEx.WhenAll(tasks);
```

I know how to achieve that with subsequent/extra enumerations, but I was wondering how to do all that in one enumeration? It's important because the `i.IsValid` operation is actually expensive and I would like to only call that once in order to do the filtering...

Comment: Do you expect `Trace.WriteLine(i.Name)` to run for all of the objects in `items` or just the ones that end up in `tasks`?

Comment: Also if you need to get the number of tasks returned then `tasks.Count()` is going to be your only way (or at least the shortest/fastest way) of doing so.

Comment: @M.Babcock Yes I would like to trace all the objects, is there a way to stick it into one enumeration?

Comment: One enumeration object, yes ([see Jon Skeet's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8781151/635634)). One iteration through the enumeration, I don't believe so. I'm having trouble understanding why you would need to. I understand you said that `i.IsValid` is heavy but the two things you said you want to do with the enumeration after it is filtered shouldn't access it.

Comment: @M.Babcock was just wondering if it is possible to put side-operations in the middle like that ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you're only taking 100 items anyway, I'd just use `ToList` to force it to be in a list:

```
var tasks = (from i in items
             where i.IsValid
             orderby i.Priority 
             select i.GetTask()).Take(100).ToList();
```

Then you can iterate over them to trace them, easily get the count, and pass the list to `TaskEx.WhenAll`.